# Pending Transaction on Goerli

Tags: transactions, hardhat, testrpc, pending-transactions, goerli

I've started the Ethernaut challenge. I have a problem with forever pending transaction on Goerli, here is the link : https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x93d1d44d7270ec53874751d20ebe65ba2f9c53249562c3e263cb5cb6d01baeae

What I don't understand is that my transaction is not on the mempool of pending transaction here : https://goerli.etherscan.io/txsPending

I'm probably doing something wrong on the signing?

I'm using hardhat to submit my transaction
Here is my test file :

```typescript
import { Contract, Signer } from "ethers";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { formatEtherscanTx } from "./utils";

let accounts: Signer[];
let eoa: Signer;
let attacker: Contract;
let challenge: Contract; // challenge contract
let tx: any;

before(async () => {
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    [eoa] = accounts;
    const challengeFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Fallback");
    challenge = challengeFactory.attach(
        `0xA6D6a254309C58273C02CE3D4312151609E977b6`
    );
    console.log("Initialiazed!");
});

it("solves the challenge", async function () {
    console.log("contribute");
    tx = await challenge.contribute({
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(`1`, `wei`),
    });
    console.log(formatEtherscanTx(tx.hash));
    await tx.wait();

    console.log("sendTransaction");
    tx = await eoa.sendTransaction({
        to: challenge.address,
        value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(`1`, `wei`),
    });
    console.log(formatEtherscanTx(tx.hash));
    await tx.wait();

    console.log("withdraw");
    tx = await challenge.withdraw();
    console.log(formatEtherscanTx(tx.hash));
    await tx.wait();
    console.log("withdrawn !");
});
```

Hardhat config :

```typescript
networks: {
        goerli: {
            url: ARCHIVE_URL,
            accounts,
            gasPrice: 120000000000,
        },
        hardhat: {
            accounts,
            forking: {
                url: ARCHIVE_URL,
                blockNumber: 7760124,
            },
        },
    },
```

With `ARCHIVE_URL` my Infura endpoint.

Here is the same [transaction](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4945bd6ad50ed68f259a234db2bb2f702939fe920d8abb9873e96146a1df251e) with Gwei auto calculation, which is still pending too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pass and took a long time. My advice is to put high gasFee (200 Gwei works well) on testnet.
Happy coding everyone

Answer (score 1):

I also had forever pending transactions on mumbai, but it was because I was playing with nonces.

I sent a transaction with much higher nonce, and it was stuck because providers are required to process nonces sequentially. Meaning, if your last transaction nonce was 9, and you send a new tx with 11 it will be stuck until the tx with nonce=10 will be sent.

Just saying this in case someone stumbles upon this problem too :))

Comment: THIS IS MY PROBLEM THANK YOU

Comment: Indirectly, but my local deploy scripts are increasing the nonce even if the transaction is not confirmed on the chain. and currently I have a buuuunch of them waiting behind one with a low gas price value.